# Where was this photo taken? Windows 10 photo lock screen

Tags: thailand, where-on-earth, lock-screens

This photo popped upon my screen today, and I would actually really like to travel to this location one day. Does anyone know where it was taken?
[image]

Comment: there are many beach piers in the world. It would be a challenge to prove which exact one it was.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you try Google? http://www.where-is-this.com/index/view/5833.html

It is **Casalunar Pier in Thailand**.
Lat/Lng: 13.247023658623932, 100.92877085174939

[image]

Comment: I think this has too many lights to be a match

Comment: Lights can be fixed or removed or switched on or off. So that shouldn't be a criteria to differentiate unless if they were on streets, maybe or explicit light stands were there.

Comment: I did not put the picture, someone else added that to the answer

Comment: @Aganju Right, but I'm pretty sure the picture I added is of the same place, right?

Comment: I think so. But it was probably years earlier or later, as they added more lights (or removed some). For me it's clear it is the same place.